# Self-hosted Integration Runtime stops working after variable hours running

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I set up a hybrid cloud environment using private endpoint connection via Site2Site VPN Connection. So far so good, i am using a Data Factory with a self-hosted integration runtime on a VM On Premise to access the On Premise data stored in a SQL Server.

Unfortunately during a copy activity or when in idle state, the Integration Runtime stops connecting/ working after some hours.
After a restart of the VM, the Self-hosted Integration Runtime works fine again.
How can I get the Runtime to work without the regulary restart of the VM?

Answer (score 0):

The disconnect and crushing of the SHIR was based by the allowed packet size inside the firewall and a packet loss from these setting.
Microsoft suggest to set the TCP MSS Clamping to 1,350 bytes and tunnel interface to 1,400 for VPN Connections, then the packets are all been delivered to Azure Cloud: [TCP/IP performance tuning for Azure VMs | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-tcpip-performance-tuning)